# Cargar una imagen en HTML

Tags: html, android-studio

Veran, estoy haciendo un programa en el cual hay que mostrar, mediante código HTML, un mensaje (el clásico "Hola Mundo") y un sprite ("sonrisa.png" lo he llamado).

Codigo XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<WebView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/webkit"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >
</WebView>
```

Codigo java:

```
package com.example.pcx.feliz;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        WebView browser=findViewById(R.id.webkit);
        String cad="<html><body>Hola Mundo<br><img src='sonrisa.png'></body></html>";
        browser.loadDataWithBaseURL("file://mnt/sdcard/img/",cad,"text/html","UTF-8",null);
    }
}
```

Cuando lo ejecuto, el "Hola Mundo aparece", pero no la imagen.
No se en que carpeta la debería poner.

Tengo entendido que, como quiero ejecutar el programa en un telefono movil, tengo que poner la imagen en mi movil (por ejemplo, en la carpeta de imagenes o la de descargas).

Pero no se sobre rutas en telefonos moviles.

Edito: He probado el siguiente codigo en java:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        WebView browser=findViewById(R.id.webkit);

        String pathExternalStorage = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath().toString();
        String imagePath = pathExternalStorage + "/" + "sonrisa.jpg";

        String cad = "file://" + imagePath;

        browser.loadDataWithBaseURL("file://mnt/sdcard/img/",cad,"text/html","UTF-8",null);
    }
```

Y cuando ejecuto el programa, me encuentro lo siguiente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me muestra una posible ruta. Pero aun la cuestión es que quiero que se muestre la imagen.
Por cierto, con ES File Explorer he mirado la ruta de la imagen y me encuentro con esta ruta: /storage/emulated/0/Download

Answer (score 0):

Lo común es cargar imágenes desde los `assets` (directorio `/assets`) de esta forma:

```
 webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/imagen.jpg");
```

pero en este caso deseas acceder a una imagen que se encuentra en el almacenamiento externo.

Lo mejor para obtener el path del almacenamiento externo es usar el método `getExternalStorageDirectory()` del SDK, de otra forma tu aplicación puede funcionar en algunos dispositivos.

```
 String base = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath().toString();
```

**Cargar la imagen directamente en el WebView.**

Suponiendo que tienes una imagen llamada `imagen.jpg` en la raíz del almacenamiento externo.

```
  String pathExternalStorage = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath().toString();
  String imagePath = pathExternalStorage + "/" + "imagen.jpg";

    /*

    //Puedes revisar si el archivo existe. 
    File archivo = new File(imagePath);
    if(archivo.exists()){
        Log.i("TAG" , "EXISTE " + imagePath);
    }else{
        Log.e("TAG" , "NO EXISTE " +imagePath );
    }
    */

  String imagePath = "file://" + imagePath;
  webView.loadUrl(imagePath);
```

**Cargando imagen mediante template html en un WebView.**

Otro método es crear un template html y agregar la ruta de la imagen:

```
 String pathExternalStorage = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath().toString();
 String imagePath = pathExternalStorage + "/" + "imagen.jpg";

String imagePathWV = "file://" + imagePath;
String html = ("<html><head></head><body><img src=\""+ imagePathWV + "\"></body></html>");
webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, html, "text/html","utf-8",null);
```

Comment: Pues sigue sin aparecer la imagen, aunque he logrado un progreso.

Comment: Actualizo para indicar que me ha pasado.

Comment: Algún comentario para el -1 ?